# TableLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

i have a Problem with my Table Layout.
Without using the ScrollView my Table looks like it's supposed to look. Now i want to add additional buttons to this class. I tried to do this with a scroll view but everyTime i add a ScrollView all my Buttons are just a thin line on the screen. I tried to fix the Problem with match_parent like other threads told me but it didn't worked. Can u help me?

```
  <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sehenswürdigkeiten"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Petersdom" 
                android:background="#8dd2ed"
                android:onClick="btnPetersdom"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Petersplatz" 
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Kolosseum" 
                android:background="#b5d597"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Pantheon" 
                android:background="#8dd2ed"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Forum Romanum" 
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Spanische Treppe" 
                android:background="#b5d597"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Kapitol" 
                android:background="#8dd2ed"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Engelsburg" 
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sehenswürdigkeiten"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Petersdom"
                android:background="#8dd2ed"
                android:onClick="btnPetersdom"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Petersplatz"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Kolosseum"

                android:background="#b5d597"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Pantheon"
                android:background="#8dd2ed"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Forum Romanum"
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Spanische Treppe"
                android:background="#b5d597"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="Kapitol"
                android:background="#8dd2ed"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Engelsburg"
                android:background="#f7bc8d"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i changed it a little but your solution worked for me!